# flip activity in android

Tags: android, gesture, swipe, flip

I'm developing an android application and I want flipping in my application (like iPhone).
When the user touches the screen and swipes left or right it should change the activity.

Does anyone have suggestions as to how I could implement this in code?

Answer (score 3):

try this
http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html

Answer (score 0):

I have another Solution:

If you want to flip not only one view but the whole screen with all views, you have only one possibility: you must use Fragment and flip them. For this  use google solution: [google example](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html)

So in your project use mix structure activities and fragments